# Can we get the Gnome3-Extention: Pixel-saver to be added into Ubuntu 17.10? How can we petition for this addon?

Tags: unity, gnome, merge, top-bar

[image]Our handicapped users really cannot live without this extension:

**Gnome 3 Addon: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/**

Just as DashToDock will be adopted into the new Ubuntu, can we please do the same for this extension? The extra space it saves for using a web browser (the pixels at the top of the screen being merged into the top Gnome 3 bar) is really important for our work on small screens. (This will help my handicapped staff members as well)

Can anyone help for this? *(I attached a photo using Fedora, but Ubuntu is the same way with it will be released with Gnome3).*

Comment: The "can we" questions can only really be answered by the Ubuntu team, so this is best asked on Launchpad (or on the [`ubuntu-devel-discuss`](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel-discuss) mailing list)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, i will try and ask them in that mailing group but have to figure out how to do so....

Comment: that's not difficult. Subscribe to the mailing list at the link in the previous comment using your email address, then send an email to `ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com` using the same email address describing your idea

Comment: Thank you very much. I went ahead and did so. I know the developers are busy but I hope that this feature can be added into Ubuntu so that we can merge the top bar with the current activation to save space for our vision-concerned users. On behalf of those like ourselves, Thank you kindly for guiding me to the process for making new Ubuntu Feature Requests.